# Managing thousands of annotation's in iOS

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit

So im making an iOS application where I have a map that contains thousands of annotations. And my question is the following:
The annotations are loaded from a site database and i query for new ones whenever the map is moved but this results in querying for the same annotation several times, does anyone know a good algorithm for not doing this?

And a follow up question: I only want to show annotations if im at a certain zoomLevel(I have implemented zoomlevels in my map just like in the googleMaps API). Can I somehow make some annotations invisible at a certain zoomlevel? In that case how do I do it?

EDIT:
Thanks for the tip Sanjay Chaudhry. Although I went with a slightly different approach for grouping annotations than what was suggested in the video. Although I still dont know how to effeciently query the server for annotations without flooding and querying for annotations already received.

EDIT2:
I still havn't found a good apporach on how to query for new annotations from the site without querying for ones already aquired.
Does anyone know some smart algorithm for splitting up countries into MapRects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a registered developer, watch the following video from WWDC 2011. It has a demo doing exactly that:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/visualizing-information-geographically-with-mapkit.html#visualizing-information-geographically-with-mapkit

Essentially, if there are many annotations in a small geographic area, they're replaced by a single annotation as the map is zoomed out.

Answer (score 1):

MapKit does a pretty good job of managing annotations -- it's often better to add as many as you can at once than to keep adding and removing them as the map moves. Annotations can be very small objects -- all you need is enough information to find the related data when you need it -- so you can add thousands at once without being too concerned about using too much memory.